# How to check jsonPath for value to expect on different property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, mockmvc

I have error messages that comes back in the following structure:

```
[{
   "detail": "must be unique",
   "source": {
      "pointer": "name"
   }
}]
```

I've omitted unnecessary bits for the sake of this example. In my test, I can do the following:

```
mockMvc.perform(post(URL)
   .contentType(contentType)
   .content(this.json(brand)))
   .andExpect(status().isUnprocessableEntity())
   .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].detail", is("must be unique")));
```

However, if I am testing that I get multiple errors back, `$.[0].detail` isn't always `Name`. So I need to first check what the `$.[0].source.pointer` is and then validate the detail message. I'm just unsure on how to go about doing that.

Comment: This is a bit unclear to me: `$.[0].detail` isn't always `Name`, you say, but is it ever suposed to be? And if it isn't what you expect, what is it? Are we talking about the order of the properties here?

Comment: When the entities are validated, they don't always comes back in the same order. So while `$.[0].detail` might reference `name` the first time, the next time it is validated `$.[0].detail` might be referencing `description`. So if I want to test that `name` is indeed at index 0, I need to look at the `source.pointer` at that index before I know that it is `name`.

Comment: Do you have some kind of sorting implemented on the server-side? If not, then you shouldn't be too surprised that the order can't be guaranteed.

Comment: I'm not surprised the order is not guaranteed. I think maybe you're missing the point of my question. I just want to be able to conditionally choose what part of the `jsonPath` I'm looking at, if that is even possible.

Comment: But as I understand it, you _are_ choosing what part of the jsonPath you're looking at, by selecting the item at position `[0]`. Your problem is that that element isn't always what you expect. So your test is assuming that there's a guaranteed order to the returned elements, while there really isn't one. I'd probably write my own Hamcrest matcher and use it in conjunction with `org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder` to assert the state of the response body. I don't know of any jsonPath features that enables you to select array items based on their nested properties.

Comment: Good suggestion. Alternatively, I could try and figure out how to get reliable ordering of validation errors.

Comment: Indeed, that might be the better course to take, considering it's a bit awkward to write Hamcrest matchers for JSON objects. Good luck!